# VBA in Outlook 2007 - how do I create a new folder if one doesn't already exist

Tags: vba

I am writing a script that saves file attachments to a folder.  I want to create sub-folders if they don't already exist.  Is there a quick way of doing this?  Essentially I am looking for something along the lines of:

If folder exists, then do nothing.  Else, create folder.  End if.

I know this is a silly 2 line piece of code, but any help much appreciated!  I'm using the SaveAsFile method within Outlook.MailItem.Attachments so perhaps there is a quick way of using another function which does the same?  Thanks again!

Excerpt from my current script below:

' Time stamp it
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm  ")

```
' Save folder
saveFolder = centrallocation & ticker & "\"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    ' File extension
    extension = Right(objAtt.FileName, Len(objAtt.FileName) - InStrRev(objAtt.FileName, "."))
    extension = LCase(extension)

    If extension = "xlsx" Or extension = "xls" Or extension = "xlsxm" Or extension = "xlsm" Then
        saveFolder = saveFolder & "\Model\"
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Else
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    End If

    ' go to next attachment
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this before saving your file:

```
Sub CreateFolderIfMissing(path as String)

    Dim folderExists As Boolean
    folderExists = (Dir(path) <> "")

    If (folderExists) Then Exit Sub

    MkDir path
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, the logic worked (thanks for the quick response), but when I use MkDir, it seems to automatically create a "read-only" directory... not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: What happens if you add `SetAttr path, vbNormal` after `MkDir`?